# save Strikethrough text state in Listview from ArrayAdapter Android

Tags: android

Good day, I am trying to display the state of a textview item in a listview from an array adapter. I can successfully save the items of the listview, but i can't display it back when the listview is populated again.

onitemclick:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String mytext = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

     TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
     text.setText(mytext);
     text.setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);              

    crossed_text.add(text.getText().toString());  // this is an Arraylist to store striked texts

    }
```

and when populating listview:

```
// i tried this

 dialog = new Dialog(this);
       LayoutInflater my_inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View checklistView = my_inflater.inflate(R.layout.check_list,null, false);
    dialog.setContentView(checklistView);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

        ListView list = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listview_id);
        TextView text = (TextView)list.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

    my_CheckList_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);

                for(int i = 0; i < my_CheckList_Adapter.getCount(); i++){


     TextView childtext = (TextView)list.getChildAt(i); // getting null value here

                      //childtext = (TextView)my_CheckList_Adapter.getItem(i).toString();

        if(crossed_text.contains(childtext.getText().toString())){
        childtext.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

                 }
            }

      list.setAdapter(my_CheckList_Adapter);
```

How do i get back this Strike Through State when populating the Listview?.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
if(crossed_text.get(i).contains(childtext.getText().toString())){
```

or

```
if(crossed_text.get(i).equals(childtext.getText().toString())){
```

---

EDIT:

***It is a working sample but it is more of a BAD practice sample. Don't collect the text 
   of items to get to them later use their indexes and put them into an array.
   Unless you want to search for an item in a list where you would want to use 
   a text. If you want to collect items from the list to perform actions on them
   use their indexes and then perform your actions.***

---

```
public class ListActivityArrayAdapter extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        ll.setLayoutParams(lp1);
        ll.setOrientation(1);
        lv = new ListView(this);

        final String [] data = new String[]{"test","test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test6"};
        final ArrayAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,data){
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                    TextView tv =new TextView(getContext());
                          tv.setText(data[position]);
                tv.setTextSize(24);
                return tv;
            }
        };
        lv.setAdapter(ad);
        final HashSet<String> arr = new HashSet<String>();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String text = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                arr.add(text);
                System.out.println("added: "+text);
            }
        });

        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("strike items");
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view) {
                for(String txt:arr)
                {
                   ((TextView)(lv.getChildAt(ad.getPosition(txt)))).
                   setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                }
            }
        });

        ll.addView(lv);
        ll.addView(b);
        setContentView(ll);
    }
}
```

---

cheers

Comment: thanks for the response. just realised am getting a null value for the childtext in this line TextView childtext = (TextView)list.getChildAt(i); any ideas?

Comment: list.setAdapter(my_CheckList_Adapter); set it before your for loop.

Comment: here's a nice article on how to use the ArrayAdapter http://sirinsevinc.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/109/ or there's plenty of info about adapters in this site too :)

Comment: I've updated the answer with the code i guess it's what you wanted but honestly it's an ugly solution. you would want to read about Android UX and about how to create lists with such items and CheckBoxes to select items then do some stuff on them or rather select their indexes and not the text to get to items to perform actions on them.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I was just overriding the getView method myself. i am trying to understand what you mean by bad practise and how to solve it. Are you saying when i want to save the striked text in an array, i should save their index position in the list into the array and not the actual text/string characters?.. because i am wondering how you would be able to determine if the arraylist holds the actual text to be striked when being populated. i would be comparing int positions in that case, right? or are you referring to something else.. thanks once again

Comment: yes when you click on items you keep their indexes then do your stuff there without calling any additional methods just referring to their indexes instead of the text, the search using the index is of course faster. you have index array and text array just use the selected indexes to retrieve the text and populate your new list.